# login button needs to change color if username and password match

Tags: java, android

i have a login atc whit a gray button and i need if to change green when the user id and passcode in in and its 4 digits the code enable and disable the button now so i need it to be gray when its disable and green when its enable .

```
 checkValidation();

    editText1_id.addTextChangedListener(mWatcher);
    editText1_passcode.addTextChangedListener(mWatcher);
}

private void checkValidation() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(editText1_id.getText()))
            || (TextUtils.isEmpty(editText1_passcode.getText())))
        loginbtn.setEnabled(false);
        loginbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.afripionts_submit_btn);
    else
        loginbtn.setEnabled(true);
        loginbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_change_color);
}


TextWatcher mWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                              int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        checkValidation();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

}
```

Comment: What is your problem / question?

Comment: i can not get the button to change color the code dont want to work

Comment: if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(editText1_id.getText()))
            || (TextUtils.isEmpty(editText1_passcode.getText())))
        loginbtn.setEnabled(false);
        loginbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.afripionts_submit_btn);
    else
        loginbtn.setEnabled(true);
        loginbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_change_color);
}

Comment: I might be missing something but it seems there could be some security or UX issues with this approach. To make it work you constantly have to check for match. Usually you would want to limit/throttle the number of tries. If you do that, the color change will not work after just a few character inputs. If you don't, brute forcing is possible.

Comment: To add to @Loke ’s comment (“brute forcing is possible”), no need to say you have a very weak password. 4 digits is 10^4 possible combinations, which holds at most 14 bits of information. “To limit/throttle the number of tries” is a common technique to mitigate the risk without improving password strength, but your approach is incompatible with it.

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of the button, use below code :

```
loginbtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Remember to do import :

```
import android.graphics.Color;
```

Comment: the color code is working it keeps saying the else in the if and else in not good and i don't now how to put it

Comment: The statement in your if else has more than 1 line, so please use `if{statement} else {statement}' curly bracket

Comment: Thanks Tony Ng Wei Shyang it want that and the code is working fine now

Comment: how do i replase the .isEmpty ? i need it to be <4